# Add Image Dynamically Into An Edit Text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am now self-studying android and trying to do a note application using Java.

My problem is that I cannot add images dynamically into an edit text. Even though I have searched a lot about it, I still do not get ways to make it.

Please help me, at least about the idea.

The following picture illustrates the problem I am struggling with.

[image: demo]

Comment: I didn't get the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to add an image into EditText?
Do you want to create a note application with texting and drawing feature? And you want to paint on EditText?

Comment: I am doing a funtionality of note application. whenever I take a photo using camera, the photo will dynamically be set into an edit text. Hope you get it.

Comment: So you can use RelativeLayout with a EditText and an ImageView in it

Comment: you mean we will define it in xml?

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your supporting. Thanks for your guys, I have discovered the way to add images dynamically (not in edit text, sorry for my misunderstanding)

Here my source code for someone who needs it. My code is a mess but it works.

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Move to Camera" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LinearLayout layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnMove = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

        btnMove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,113);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data != null) {
            if (requestCode == 113 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                layout.setLayoutParams(params);
                setContentView(layout);
                layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
                imgView.setLayoutParams(params);
                layout.addView(imgView);
                int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(image);
                EditText edtText = new EditText(this);
                edtText.setLayoutParams(params);
                edtText.setBackground(null);
                layout.addView(edtText);
                Button btn = new Button(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                btn.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
                btn.setText("Move to Camera");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**USE**

> `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,R.mipmap.you_image,0,0);
```

**OR**

You can add `ImageView` above the `EditText` in the xml code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what does the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` do? and when I take a photo using camera, it will be not in mipmap directory.

Comment: You can add ImageView above the EditText in the xml code .

Comment: define imageview in xml will retrict the photo I can take using camera. For example, in your xml code, I could only set image once times only (to my understanding). What I really want is that I can add photos to edit text every time I take photo using camera

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible out of the box. Just add ImageView above EditText. Or better, create custom view with EditText and LinearLayout (for dynamically added views) tied together.

Something like this (please keep in mind it's pseudo code):

**Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CustomView customView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    customView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view);

    someAction()
}

public void someAction() {
    customView.addImage(...);
}
```

**Custom View**

```
public class CustomView extends FrameLayout {

private LinearLayout dynamicViewsParent;

public CustomView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();

}

public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    View inflatedView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_view, this);
    dynamicViewsParent = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.dynamicViewsWrapper);
}

public void addImage(SomeKindOfSource source) {
    View view = createViewFrom(source);
    dynamicViewsParent.addView(view);
}
```

}

and layout for **CustomView**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/custom_view">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dynamicViewsWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEXT"/>
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be a comment or deleted altogether.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how many pictures I will take in each note. So add imageview above edit text in xml will be not good idea. Hope I get your idea right

Comment: Instead of one imageview just use linearlayout for instance (above edittext) and add children dynamically.

Comment: @LeQuynhAnh I've edited my answer to be more suitable for your problem.